# ExtJs 4 vertical DataView

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like to know is it possible to create vertical DataView [dataview docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View) [dataview sample](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/view/data-view.html)

By defaylt it renders from left to right in N rows, in other words second element at the right of the first one,

I am looking how to change this behavior to layout it vertically, so the second element will be below first one.

BTW if you know exactly that it is impossible with DataView let me know, because I think I can do it with GridView (but not in a trivial manner)

**UPDATE#1**
Desired layout should be as follows:

- 1,6
- 2,7
- 3,8
- 4,9
- 5,10

Thanks.

Comment: In the example from link that you have posted ([dataview docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View)) images are layouted verticaly. (click the "Live Preview" button)

Comment: hm, I don't think so, as I can see it layout childs in a rows, so for instnace first row contains 1,2,3,4 second 5,6,7,8, but I want to layout it in columns

Comment: I'm talking about example from the first link. And items are aligned verticaly there.

Comment: hm, sorry, can you point me preciselly, really can't see that it layouts vertically, thanks

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/11/screen194808.png/

Comment: In fact I want to have two columns, I've just updated my question so you can see desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible by using xindex, xcount and parent variables. I found it by analysing source, you probably won't find any additional information about this solution in API. Example template:

```
'<tpl for=".">',
    '<tpl if="(xindex - 1) &lt; (xcount / 2)">',
        '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
        '{src} ',
        '<tpl if="parent[xindex - 1 + Math.ceil(xcount / 2)] != undefined">',
            '{[parent[xindex - 1 + Math.ceil(xcount / 2)].src]}',
        '</tpl>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>',
'</tpl>'
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZUej/1/

Comment: Cool, it looks like only one possible solution. Thanks